# Can I use output operand as an input inside ARM inline assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, arm, inline-assembly

I have an inline assembly code with two small lines. I want to use the output operand which retrieved from first line as an input operand in my second line. I was wondering if it is possible or not. Here is my code:

```
asm volatile(   "umull          %0, %1, %3, %4; \n\t"
                "adds           %2, %5, %0;     \n\t"
                :"=r"(mullo2), "=r"(mulhi2), "=r"(temp)
                :"r"(A), "r"(B->uint32[6]), "r"(mulhi1)
                :"cc");
```

As you can see here, I need `mullo2` operand to be the one of my input in the second instruction. Compiler doesn't complain about it, but somehow I don't get correct results.

Comment: Yes, you can. Examine generated asm code (using `gcc -S` or `objdump`). Also specify what input you provide and what output you get and why that's not correct.

Comment: Not sure if I understand right, but: If you use registers inside **the same** `asm` statement only, you have to list them in the clobber section, but not as input or output. Otherwise, if you want to change an input argument, you have to make it in/out. Note that using `uint32` as a name is a bad idea, as that can easily be confused with the `uint32_t` type. In general, use self-explanatory names, not their types.

Comment: Also note that output operands might be allocated to the same registers as inputs, unless you use early-clobber. In your case `%5` may be the same as `%0` or `%1` and since those are destroyed by the first instruction, your second one would use wrong value.

Comment: @Jester The early clobber was the issue. Would you please post it as an answer. Maybe it helps someone in future

Comment: You should consider just skipping any inline asm stuff and just write whole methods in ASM. The code to generate function call and return logic can be generated once and then used as a template for your asm. The problems with attempting to do half the logic in C and half in ASM are too much to go into, but it can get scary. Starting out with an approach of writing whole functions in asm is the better way to go.

Comment: @MoDJ I believe you are right. I searched over the web for some tutorials about how to call asm functions inside c codes, but I have not understand how I can get my function arguments in asm codes. For example in this case, I have an array of unsigned integer as my function argument and I don't understand how can I access to each chunk of my array inside asm code. I would be so thankful if you can introduce me some good tutorials which get it clear for me.

Comment: Sure thing, there are quite a few good links at my blog post on this subject. Note that the provided example code for is for ARM on iOS/Xcode, but the general idea should work on any ARM platform: http://www.modejong.com/blog/post10_arm_timing_framework/index.html

Comment: Alternatively, perhaps also consider skipping the assembly hassle altogether and just bearing the underlying instruction set in mind when writing C, because [compilers can often do a damn good job if you feed them code they can understand the intention of](https://goo.gl/aqqFw5).

Comment: wow! That was amazing! Thanks a lot for your answers. I learned a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output operands might be allocated to the same registers as inputs, unless you use early-clobber. In your case `%5` may be the same as `%0` or `%1` and since those are destroyed by the first instruction, your second one would use wrong value. Thus, you should use early-clobber modifier on those two output operands, such as `"=&r"(mullo2)`